# Could someone please help me improving my post under certain viewpoints?

Tags: discussion

I just posted this question: [What to do if I was tasked to get my work asigned by a coworker but he wasn't able to do so?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/92964/26185)

I was first thinking about posting it anonymously, but I came to the conclusion, that even if someone from my company is reading it, they would quite likely be able to identify me, but it is more likely to show my commitmend, that I'm asking a question like this on my weekend, as it would look like I'm trying to badmouthing anyone. So the first viewpoint is, **could you help me improving the post by reducing the content that might make me look badmouthing or runting, while keeping the informations the same?**

The next point is(is it ok on meta to put more then one viewpoint into a post?): I'm not allowed to talk about company internas, so I tryed to me as inaccurate about that stuff as I could. **Could anyone help me improving the post regarding to reduce company itnernas that might be leaked by it, while still holding the informatiosn about the situation correct?**

And in the end: Is it worth improving the post or might it still be better to just request to get anonymized from it?

Comment: That is quite a wall of text you have there. Whenever you find yourself adding footnotes and titles in a *question*, you're usually adding too much detail. Scanning your text, is your question simply "*How can I get my colleague to assign me tasks or give me information?*"? It should be more than one line of course but that question doesn't require anywhere near as much information or detail. Scrapping most of that unnecessary info will also help conceal your identity.

Comment: @Lilienthal: yeah, I'm aware of having that problem, thats why I'm asking about it here. after I finished the text and just read it I had allready the same impression as what you said. But I'm having asperger what leads in those regards for me in having trouble seeing what is important for others and what not to get the full picture, when not giving the whole picture. Since I allready have in such a situation trouble to detect the behavior of other that lead to a problem. So I can't break it down to the real problem since I'm not quite sure what even the real problem was *sigh*

Comment: Have a look at Kate's excellent answer. She touches on the points that are actually relevant and explicitly mentions the key problems in your story that you need to address (i.e. stuff you need to resolve or bring to your manager). You can use that as a guideline in shortening your question. Your question is over a 1000 words long. I think you can fit everything into 300 or less.

Comment: @Lilienthal: Challange accpeted. But it will take me quite some time especially since phrasing it took me allready close to 2 hours and I have to leave for today. But still thanks for your input and help.

Comment: As a general note, you should usually avoid posting over the weekend on this site as it grows very quiet then. You'll get more exposure and input on both the main site and meta during the week.

Comment: @Lilienthal: yeah I noticed it allready jsut by doing it. By the way, is the post better after the recent edits, or should I still try to improve it?

Comment: It's much better yes. You could probably remove some of the details of the conversation with your coworker and summarise it as not getting the input you need, but in its present form this is probably up to our site standards. You probably should avoid using rare words like "titubation" though. With this meta thread you might be able to get some visibility on the question to get some of these downvotes reversed, but you might not get many more answers since the simple answer is that you should go to your manager. There's little else to be done and Kate's answer is fairly comprehensive.